# Calling a javascript function when URL changes

Tags: javascript, url

I'm not sure which topic I am looking for, but here's a description of what I'm trying to achieve:

- When the URL changes, a javascript method should be called instead of trying to load that URL's page.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because for SEO purposes, I need to use segmented URLs. However, I'm also trying to create the "new page" on-the-fly, using preloaded HTML templates. So instead of loading a new page, I just want to call the associated method which will render the page using templates.

Is this behavior possible?

Note: I think it is worth mentioning that the existing system currently uses URL hash to detect if a new page will be loaded.

Regards,

Erwin

Answer (score 0):

you need to append a click handler to all links where you prevent the default action and do your redirect. with jQuery this can be as easy as that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').on('click', function () {
    $(location).attr('href','your_url'); // redirect wherever you want to go
    return false;
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently.
Assuming I understand what you're after, here's the listener that executes a function on hash change

```
var last_hash = "";

setInterval(function(){
    hash = window.location.hash;

    if(last_hash != hash && hash.length != 1){
        hash = hash.substring(1)

        //Making sure that there's actually a function with that name
        if(typeof window[hash] == 'function'){
            var fn = window[hash];

            //Execute the function
            fn.apply({param: "param1"}, ["param1", "param2"]);
        }
        last_hash = window.location.hash;
    }
}, 250);
```

You can do some additional parsing of the hash by separating the function name and the parameters, then adding all the parameters to an array to pass on to the `.apply`, but I leave that part up to you.

If you're using actual urls and not hash, just make sure you prevent the default behavior of links on the page, and any links you subsequently load after that.

```
function attach_disablelinks(){
    $("a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```